# How to imitate Python 3's raise ... from in Python 2?

Tags: python-2.7, exception, python-3.x, traceback, raise

Python 3 has the neat

```
try:
    raise OneException('sorry')
except OneException as e:
    # after a failed attempt of mitigation:
    raise AnotherException('I give up') from e
```

syntax which allows raising a followup exception without loosing context. The best analogy I could come up with in Python 2 is

```
raise AnotherException((e,'I give up')), None, sys.exc_info()[2]
```

where the `(e,'')` is an ugly hack to have the original exception's name included in the message. But isn't there a better way?

Comment: You could do just `raise` without any argument, but I don't think you could change the type to `AnotherException` if you did that.

Comment: @Kevin I know, this is just a simplification - in a more realistic case this would be something like a file not found exception and its failsafe also failing, thus yielding a different exception with some other message as well, but the original exception should be conserved

Comment: I don't think Python 2 provides proper support for anything like this.  I suppose you could wrap your ugly hack in a `reraise()` function or something.  Given the [release schedule for 2.8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404), you might consider switching to 3.x.  Do you have any 2.x-only dependencies?

Comment: @Kevin https://hg.python.org/peps/rev/76d43e52d978?utm_content=buffer55d59&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer :P Currently the major reason I use Python 2.7 is PythonXY (Windows), but I'm also asking out of curiosity

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's a [`raise_from`](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html?highlight=raise_from#raising-exceptions) in [python-future](http://python-future.org/quickstart.html); simply install it

```
pip install future
```

and import to use

```
from future.utils import raise_from
# or: from six import reraise as raise_from

class FileDatabase:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        try:
            self.file = open(filename)
        except IOError as exc:
            raise_from(DatabaseError('failed to open'), exc)
```

### UPDATE

The compatibility package [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) also supports [`raise_from`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.raise_from), from version 1.9 (released in 2015). It is used in the same manner as above.

Comment: Hi. raise_from in `six` actually imitates plain raise(exec) in python2, so it doesn't get python 3 behavior :(

Comment: Yes, `raise_from` in `six` imitates plain raise. But `reraise`, also from `six`, worked. See the example in this link: http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html or in my suggested solution.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using six.raise_from, try to use six.reraise, as explained in this page:

http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html

```
from six import reraise as raise_ 
# or from future.utils import raise_

traceback = sys.exc_info()[2]
raise_(ValueError, "dodgy value", traceback)
```

Comment: `six.reraise` sets the trace, not `__cause__`. This question is asking about explicit chaining, which sets the latter.